# How can I solve 500 internal server error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

My code is like this ;

```
public function setMain($id)
{
    $users_banks = UsersBank::get()->toArray();
    $res = ['status'=>''];
    foreach ($users_banks as $users_bank ) {
        if($users_bank['id'] == $id) {
            $param['status'] = 1;
            $res = ['status'=>'modified'];
            $this->user_bank_repository->update($id, $param);
        } else {
            $param['status'] = 0;
            $this->user_bank_repository->update($id, $param);
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

When executed, on the console exist error :  500 internal server error

But, I edit the code to be static like this :

```
public function setMain($id)
{
    $param['status'] = 1;
    $res = ['status'=>'modified'];
    $this->user_bank_repository->update($id, $param);

    return $res;
}
```

It's no error

Whether there is something wrong with my code?

I use laravel 5.3

Comment: The errors will be printed out to the php error log if you have it set up to do so. On console it might be configured to print out errors instead. Have you taken a look at the error log?

Comment: @jedifans, I see on laravel.log. No error

Comment: Some frameworks don't catch fatal errors, so they would end up in the php error log, which is separate to the laravel.log - have a hunt for it. On Linux hosts it could be /var/log/php/error.log but your php.ini will say for sure.

Comment: Can you disable the else part & check if any errors @samueltoh

Comment: In my experience i see this error many times if I forgot to chmod storage folder. Try `chmod 777 -R storage` and then run the code. In my case after I chmod folder it will show the error. Or write error in laravel.log.